# Is it possible to have a "vertically-oriented" grid using ag-grid? (not pivot table)

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

The default layout for a grid in `ag-grid` is what I call "horizontal" (with respect to the rows):

- Columns are laid out vertically, spanning top-to-bottom.
- Rows are laid out "across the columns", aka, spanning the horizon.
- New rows get appended to the bottom.

**Pictorially:**
[image: horizontal grid]

I am needing grids to be "flipped" (aka, "vertical") in certain scenarios, such that:

- Columns are laid out horizontally.
- Rows are laid out vertically, spanning top-to-bottom.
- New rows get appended to the right.

**Pictorially:**
[image: vertical grid]

**Is this possible with `ag-grid`?**
I don't think their pivot table will work for this, but maybe I'm not thinking creatively enough :)
These grids are being used in an Angular app.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only solution is for you to write the transpose logic on your raw data and Column definitions by yourself.

Here is an excellent example and a video explainer to go along with it:

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/github/LMFinney/ag-grid-partial

Blog: https://blog.oasisdigital.com/2018/transposing-rows-and-columns-in-ag-grid/

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BR9sH7zG7g